# MapStruct : How to convert String to byte[] using mapstruct

Tags: spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

In My dto class :

```
private String password;
```

In my model class:

```
private byte[] password;
```

I want to convert String to byte[] using mapStruct. Can someone help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Best would be to provide a default method for mapping between `String` and `byte[]`.

For example:

```
@Mapper
public MyMapper {

    Model fromDto(Dto dto);

    default byte[] toBytes(String string) {
        return string != null ? string.getBytes() : null;
    }

}
```

With this you will have MapStruct do automatic for all of your other fields between `Dto` and `Model` and leave the mapping between `String` and `byte[]` to the `toBytes` method.